# Sorting different type of objects (performance)

Tags: java, performance, sorting

Let's say I have a class called Unit (with a position variable x) and extend the class to UnitA, UnitB, UnitC, etc..

this is something I came up with:

```
Unit[] ordered = new Unit[a_num+b_num+c_num];
ordered = Arrays.copyOf(a_units, a_num); //and add b_units, c_units, etc
Arrays.sort(ordered); //sort using compareTo method
```

- For best performance and neat programming, what is the best way to sort these values from left to right (the x variable)?
- When the array is sorted, in order to access unit specific variables, how do I find out what type of object each entry is?

Comment: Why do you create an array of Unit in the first line and throw it away in the second line?

Comment: Exactly what I said.  In the first line you create an array of Unit.  In the second line you overwrite that reference with the reference returned from Arrays.copyOf.  If you're worried about performance, don't do useless stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Arrays.sort(ordered)` will sort based on the natural ordering (defined by the compareTo method) of the units. If the natural ordering is not what you want, then use `Arrays.sort(array, Comparator)` and pass a comparator which compares the position of the units.

Regarding your second question: you shouldn't have to know the type of the units. Your Unit class should provide polymorphic methods that you can call and which are implemented by every subclass to do the appropriate thing. There's always the `instanceof` operator and the `getClass()` method, but using them shows a lack of OO design, and is thus bad practice.

Comment: Thank you, this should help me get started!

Answer (score 5):

If you have to find out what type of object each entry is, you've done it wrong.

Polymorphism is the only way to go.  That's what object-oriented languages are for.

You don't say how you want to sort units.  Do you mean physical units, like meters for length, kilograms for mass, seconds for time?  If yes, what does "sorting" them mean?  You can order them alphabetically, of course, but I don't know how meaningful that is.

What is the "position variable"?  Do you mean that you'll have a Unit for lengths with underlying values like meter, foot, angstrom, and furlong in different "positions"?  And how will you order them?  By popularity?  The answer changes depending on whether you're in one of the few countries left that still use British units (e.g. the United States; even England gave up imperial units!) or metric.

Comment: Each Unit object has an x variable and I want to sort all the extended Objects on this x variable in a descending way.

Comment: Tells me nothing.  It's a tautology.  Voting to close.